# Trying to parse XML in Perl, but long data string gets cutoff

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

I've tried to parse an XML file with XML::Simple and XML::Twig with the same result. The other fields in the file works just fine.

The file in question can be retrieved here:

```
curl -s "http://apps.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/services/mpconnect_service.cfm?mainSearchCriteria.v.cs=2.16.840.1.113883.6.103&mainSearchCriteria.v.c=130"
```

Is this a problem with the parser or the file? The output was the same with both parsers. The HTML-tags in the string is stored in the XML

Input field (inside xml-tags named 'summary'):

```
<summary type="html">&lt;p&gt;Toxoplasmosis is a disease caused by the parasite &lt;em&gt;Toxoplasma gondii&lt;/em&gt;. More than 60 million people in the U.S. have the parasite.  Most of them don't get sick. But the parasite causes serious problems for some people. These include people with weak immune systems and babies whose mothers become infected for the first time during pregnancy. Problems can include damage to the brain, eyes and other organs.&lt;/p&gt;&#xd;^I&#xd;&lt;p&gt;You can get toxoplasmosis from &lt;/p&gt;&#xd;&lt;ul&gt;&#xd;&lt;li&gt;^IWaste from an infected cat&lt;/li&gt;&#xd;&lt;li&gt;^IEating contaminated meat that is raw or not well cooked &lt;/li&gt;&#xd;&lt;li&gt;^IUsing utensils or cutting boards after they've had contact with raw meat &lt;/li&gt;&#xd;&lt;li&gt;^IDrinking infected water &lt;/li&gt;&#xd;&lt;li&gt;^IReceiving an infected organ transplant or blood transfusion&lt;/li&gt;&#xd;&lt;/ul&gt;&#xd;&lt;p&gt;Most people with toxoplasmosis don't need treatment. There are drugs to treat it for pregnant women and people with weak immune systems. &lt;/p&gt;&#xd;&#xd;&lt;p class="NLMattribution"&gt;Centers for Disease Control and Prevention&lt;/p&gt;</summary>
```

Output after XML-parsing:

```
<p>Toxoplasmosis is a disease caused by the parasite <em>Toxoplasma gondii</em>. More than 60 million people in the U.S. have the parasite.  Most of them don't get sick. But the parasite causes serious problems for some people. These include people with weak im<p class="NLMattribution">Centers for Disease Control and Prevention</p>to treat it for pregnant women and people with weak immune systems. </p>her organs.</p>
```

**Solution to the problem:**
The XML files contains a carriage return "" which causes problems for the parsers. After I downloaded the XML files I removed the carriage returns with the following line:

```
sed -i 's/&#xd;//g' *.xml
```

The parsers now works as expected.

**Update:**
The carriage return does not affect the parser, only the output which appears truncated and mixed up. Removing it did however solve my problem.

Comment: if you know the solution, then close the question please...

Comment: actually the &#xd; characters do not cause problems for the parsers. I suspect they cause problems when you print the result though. Especially if you're working on a Unix box. If you output the result to a file, you should be able to see the whole text, including some ^M characters that make it look like part of the text is missing when you print it. It's hard to tell without seeing your code though.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be right, mirod. The printed output is wrong, with some parts removed and other parts in between others. I've updated the post with this info.

Comment: you got me worried for a while! XML::Twig specifically buffers the whole content of text elements so you don't have to worry about it (I assume XML::Simple does the same thing BTW). This kind of problem is a pain to figure out, because it messes up the tools you use to analyze it, in this case print.

Comment: Sorry about that, but anyway thanks for your help! I was searching a bit for buffering documentation for the different parsers, but I didn't find anything particular about Twig. Good to know that it wasn't the parser's problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do get some weird results when parsing the curl as a pipe (using `XML::Twig->new->parse( curl -s "http://..." |`): the content appears truncated, changes from call to call...

Things look better if I parse a file created from the curl result, or XML::Twig's native `parseurl` method, then the result is constant, and what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig    = XML::Twig->new->parseurl( "http://apps.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/services/mpconnect_service.cfm?mainSearchCriteria.v.cs=2.16.840.1.113883.6.103&mainSearchCriteria.v.c=130" );
my $summary = $twig->first_elt( 'summary');

print $summary->text, "\n";
```

Honestly I have no idea why this happens. I'll try looking into it a little more, but I suspect there is nothing I can do: if the problem shows up in both XML::Simple and XML::Twig, then it's probably at a lower level of the stack, XML::Parser or expat and their interaction with curl.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried both of your examples, with parse ( curl..) and parseurl (.., but the first did not work and the second also produce a truncated (but constant) result. I'm now looking into if buffering limitations could be the problem, [http://perl-xml.sourceforge.net/faq/#char_events](http://perl-xml.sourceforge.net/faq/#char_events). I am also working on local xml files, downloaded via curl, which has the full text intact.

Comment: are you sure you get the whole content? When you parse the url, try saving the complete XML to see if the text is all there.

Comment: Yes, the output from the local xml via XML::Twig->new->parsefile and the output from parseurl are identical.